# Django render CheckboxSelectMultiple with icons from the model

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class PackageCategoryChoices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

and this form

```
class TripForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=PackageCategoryChoices.objects.all())
```

Basically I'm saving an icon in the database and I just want to render it into a form. I'm unable to access the model information from the template or add extra models fields to the form field.

I want something like:

```
  <div class="checkbox">
     <label for="id_categories_1"><input id="id_categories_1" name="categories" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
     <span class="glyphicons envelope"></span><!-- this is the icon -->
      Paquete pequeño<!-- this is the name -->
     </label>
  </div>
```

I tried changing the __unicode_ method but it made a conflict with other forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance` method:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class IconChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return format_html('<span class="glyphicons {}"></span> {}',
                           obj.icon, obj.name)

class TripForm(forms.Form):
    categories = IconChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                 queryset=PackageCategoryChoices.objects.all())
```